# How to replace the first occurrence of a string in a line while writing the line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am pulling lines out of a larger file that meet a specific criteria out and writing them to a new file. I need to replace the first occurrence of ":" with ":|" in each line.

I didn't know I needed to do this when I wrote my first Python (3.8) script to pull the lines which is this successful code:

```
with open('path/freakinginput.txt', 'r') as i, open('path/freakingoutput.txt', 'w') as o:
     for line in i:
        if (line.find('RQSTSVCS') != -1):
             o.write(line)
```

As you might expect, this results in a file of all the lines that contain the string RQSTSVCS and it makes a tidy table.

I thought that I could just do:

```
with open('path/freakinginput.txt', 'r') as i, open('path/freakingoutput.txt', 'w') as o:
    for line in i:
        if (line.find('RQSTSVCS') != -1):
            o.write(line.replace(':',':|',1))
```

Nothing happens when I do this way but I am at a loss. I have tried different ways of defining the line, for instance:

```
o.write(line).replace(':',':|',1)
```

which still doesn't work.

I'm not getting any errors. Python just doesn't write the output.

Please be gentle. I'm pretty darned good at C++ scripting but I'm really new to Python and have been thrown into the deep end of a project. Thank y'all in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the condition `if (line.find('RQSTSVCS') != -1):` is being met?

Comment: If the first version works then the second one should too. The only explanation I can think of is that the contents of `freakinginput.txt` changed in between these two attempts; did you accidentally overwrite it?

Comment: When you say "doesn't write the output", does it not write _any_ output, or does it write _some_ output, just the lines unchanged?  (Side note: you might consider writing `if 'RQSTSVCS' in line:` instead of using `line.find`)

Comment: When you say "nothing happens when I do this way", you mean the output file is unchanged? Are you sure that you're looking at the right output file / the most recent version of it? Are you sure your colon really is a colon?

Comment: Thanks, Kaya! I thought about that. To check the original file, I tried running the original code without modification and it happily wrote the RQST-2.txt file. with the unmodified lines.

Comment: Apologies. When I say nothing happens, it means that no output file gets written at all.

Comment: I am editing my code in UltraEdit. The colons seem to be working in the original code and I am typing them using the colon on my keyboard.

Comment: @TobeyMiller thanks for the response.  In that case, consider replacing the `o.write(...)` line with `print("match:", line)` and seeing if you get any output.  My guess is that you won't, and it'd be because "RQSTSVCS" isn't found in any of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

y'all!

I don't know why I didn't think of downloading an editor before but I put my code into PyCharm and I was able to figure out the proper placement of the `replace()` method.
This is the correct code:

```py
with open('path/freakinginput.txt', 'r') as i, open('path/freakingoutput.txt', 'w') as o:
    for line in i:
        if line.find('RQSTSVCS') != -1:
            o.write(line.replace(':', ':|', 1))
```

I'm awful thankful for your input and I appreciate you!
Tobey